# $(ms^{-1})^2$ - How does this work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am really sorry for the junior question but I have a friend who does not understand this. I have been trying to explain this countless times but he does not understand and is convinced that 
$$(ms^{-1})^2$$
is (1) below instead of (2):

1. $ms^{-2}$.
2. $m^2s^{-2}$.

Comment: I edited to remove the large image; I hope that's fine with you.

Comment: Since $x^2$ means $xx=x\times x$, then
$$(ms^{-1})^2 = (ms^{-1})(ms^{-1}) = ms^{-1}ms^{-1} = mms^{-1}s^{-1} = m^2s^{-2}.$$

Comment: Does your friend understand the difference between $(ab)^2$ and $ab^2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(a\cdot b)^2 = (a\cdot b)\cdot(a\cdot b)=a\cdot b\cdot a\cdot b=a\cdot a\cdot  b\cdot b=a^2\cdot b^2$$

Now set $a=m$ and $b=s^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps it will help if you use an example: $m = 4$, $s=2$.